# Parcel JS. Use of --public-url option

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, frontend, parceljs

I am using Parcel JS for a personal project and I am really confused by this option:

--public-url

Here is the documentation: https://en.parceljs.org/cli.html#options

which is really scarce.

1) What is the main use of it?
2) It says that it is available in: *serve*, *watch* and *build*.
Is there any difference between these 3 options while using *--public-url*?
3) And last but not least, how  *--public-url* and *--out-dir* work together? Is there any limitation on the setup when we use both options at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

1. `--public-url` is used to specify from where the bundled assets are served.

As an example:

The default value is `--public-url /`, which generates tags like this.

```
<script src="/src.133713ex.js">
```

Which doesn't work if the site is not served from the domains root.

E.g. on a Github Pages site where the URLs are `username.github.io/project-name/`, here you would need to serve them from the index.html files location.

That's where `--public-url` comes in to play:

```
--public-url ./
```

By adding this to our build options we change the generated tag to the following, which would work.

```
<script src="src.133713ex.js">
```

2. It just means you can use it with every way there is to start a parcel process.
3. Yes they do work together! `--out-dir` just defines the directory where the bundled files are generated (default is /dist) and `--public-url` functions as explained above.

Comment: Great answer thanks, but doesn't it make sense to be on "./" as its default value in the first place?

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I wish this was explained better in the documentation

Comment: For me, using GitHub pages I had to additionally specify a `target` property with `publicUrl` containing the project name. https://parceljs.org/features/targets#publicurl

Answer (score 8):

NB: if you change `--public-url`, you may have to delete the `.parcel-cache` folder before building in order to see the changes reflected in your site. Otherwise, in my experience, `index.html` attempts to access the same file paths as as before the `public-url` change.